# Emberjs Checkbox Save to Database

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ember.js

I have a checkbox that needs to save to the database as soon as the value is changed. It is bound to the data element audit. Here is the checkbox in the template:

```
{{view Site.ReleaseChecklistToggleView checkedBinding="audit" contentBinding="this" placeholder="#"}}
```

Here is what the `Site.ReleaseChecklistToggleView` is defined as:

```
Site.ReleaseChecklistToggleView = Em.Checkbox.extend(
    change: (e)->
        this.content.save()
)
```

It appears that audit is not being set before change is called. It passes the `audit` variable as `null` to the database, but if I do `console.log(this.content.audit)` in the `change` method, then it tells me the correct value of `true` or `false`. My only conclusion is that it is not updating the ember model until after the change method is being run.

Any advice? Am I using the wrong method?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Site.ReleaseChecklistToggleView = Em.Checkbox.extend(
  valueChanged: ->
    @get("content").save()
.observes("checked"))
```

Comment: That did not seem to work. It ended up saving twice (neither save had the correct data) and then resetting the checkbox back to the previous state.

Comment: Any chance you could put together a jsBin?

Comment: You could also observe the change in your model by including auditChanged: function() { this.save(); }.observes('audit'),

Comment: I tried observing audit in the model, and that worked, except it also ran when the page loaded, and that caused some problems.

Comment: You might be able to check this.get('isLoaded') before saving. Not sure if that works in the latest versions of ED though.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Ember guide for the Todo application (http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/). I was able to get auto-saving of a specific attribute working through a checkbox by following this.

In case that link is no longer active, this is how they did it...

Handlebars

```
<!--- ... additional lines truncated for brevity ... -->
{{#each itemController="todo"}}
  <li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
    <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
  </li>
{{/each}}
<!--- ... additional lines truncated for brevity ... -->
```

Controller

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isCompleted: function(key, value){
    var model = this.get('model');

    if (value === undefined) {
      // property being used as a getter
      return model.get('isCompleted');
    } else {
      // property being used as a setter
      model.set('isCompleted', value);
      model.save();
      return value;
    }
  }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```